# Is there a way to format article layout on joomla?

Tags: joomla2.5

How can I format article's layout...

For example I would like to display the first image on top under the title but, on the left of the text I would like a column with the date, hits, author name and pic, and any other stuff I like to have there...

Is it posible?

Thanks again for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out Joomla overrides. Here's one link to get you started:
http://bit.ly/Z97yls

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood of your question, you can easily do this with CSS classes - use google chrome to inspect the code.

Also, there is a amazing component called [Modules Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/6402) that you can use to insert any module inside your articles page.